# Unable to load HSQL JDBC driver in WildFly 10 "Servlet Only" distribution

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, wildfly, hsqldb

Seeing the following in my WildFly log when I try to deploy my WAR (which does run just fine in Jetty):

```
08:30:34,873 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot 
create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test'
08:30:34,876 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) Exception encountered during context initialization 
- cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.demo.FhirServerCo
nfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalCo
ntainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested serv
ice [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

This is then followed by a whole bunch of knock-on exceptions and their stack traces, and the WAR fails to load.

Again: this same WAR runs just fine in Jetty, and if I turn on WildFly's debug logging, I do see the HSQL JAR being loaded from the WAR. It just... doesn't *actually* load it to the classpath? I don't know.

Comment: Not a wildfly user myself but perhaps hsqldb.jar is part of the wildfly distribution so there's dupes on the classpath?

Comment: The other messages may be important. I'm not a Spring expert but I think it attempts to determine the running container in some instances and assumes some behavior. It's possible that WildFly Servlet Only doesn't have a feature Spring is expecting.